# Install custom jars azure devops maven artifact

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, mule, azure-pipelines

I have custom dependency jars files in our local maven repo folder like com.org.* to build a Mule application. 
I have installed these jars files using `mvn install` command so that it will get published to maven local repo and again pulled by pom.xml.

Now, I have to replicate the same thing inside azure DevOps under the maven tab. 
I have been struggling a lot to find a solutions. Azure DevOps experts could you please guide me here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Install custom jars azure devops maven artifact

You could create your custom maven feed on the Azure DevOps, then publish those custom dependency jars files into this custom maven feed, and use `mvn install` command with [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops).

For the details info, please check following documents:

[Set up Azure Pipelines and Maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/maven?view=azure-devops)

[Get started with Maven packages in Azure DevOps Services and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops)

[Configure Azure DevOps Services for Maven package management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/labs/mavenpmvsts/?view=azure-devops)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried publishing artifacts to azure but am getting.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project jms-2.0: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xyc:jms-2.0:jar:2.0 from/****/test/maven/v1): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: could you please help me with how to troubleshoot for the above issue?

Comment: @veejayD, This should be another question, I suggest that you could open a new thread with more info, like the steps about what have you done and the error log.